# nested loop wont execute queries in internal loop with length bigger than 1

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, nested-loops

Sorry guys i couldn't provide feedback because of my other username and password here, anyways here is the issue:

I'm working on a SOAP based webservice where in a part of it i have to perform some queries on the database using nested loop, the problem is that the inner loop just gets executed for ONE time only, before giving up.This is the code:

```
for(int i=0; i<selec.length; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<sintom.length;j++){
    var[(i*sintom.length)+j] = 
      "INSERT INTO malattia (nome, eta,  descrizione, sesso, etnia, sintomi) "
      + "VALUES ('" + malattia + "','" + eta + "','" + descrizione + "','" 
      +  sexarra[0] + "','" + selec[i] + "','" + sintom[j] + "')";
  }
}
```

This is where the queries are supposed to get executed:

```
if (errore.equals("")) {
  try {
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    for(int i=0; i<selec.length; i++){
      for(int j=0;j<sintom.length;j++){
        st.executeUpdate(var[(i*sintom.length)+j]);
      }
    }
```

What happens is that no matter the size of `select` it will work fine as long as the length of **sintom** is 1, larger than 1 and it won't work.

**UPDATE**
I just used prepared statement but the problem persists, if the length of the inner loop is bigger than 1, it won't work! here is the code to the changes i made:

```
if (errore.equals("")) {
  try {
    /*  Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        Statement[] si=new Statement[selec.length];
        for(int i=0;i<selec.length;i++)
        si[i]=conn.createStatement();               */
   PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
     "INSERT INTO malattia (nome, eta, descrizione, sesso, etnia, sintomi) 
      values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");


     for(int i=0; i<selec.length; i++){
       for(int j=0;j<sintom.length;j++){
         //  si[i].executeUpdate(var[(i*sintom.length)+j]);
         ps.setString(1, malattia);
         ps.setInt(2, eta);
         ps.setString(3, descrizione);
         ps.setString(4, sexarra[0] );
         ps.setString(5, selec[i]);
         ps.setString(6, sintom[j]);
         ps.executeUpdate();
       }
     }
   }  
   //st.executeUpdate(q);
   ps.close();
   conn.close();
   ris = "si";
```

Complete Server Code:

```
             public String aggiungi_malattia(String malattia, int eta, String descrizione, String[] sexarra, String[] selec, String[] sintom) {
        String ris = "no";
         String errore = connetti();
         if (errore.equals("")) {
              try {
               PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO malattia (nome, eta, descrizione, sesso, etnia, sintomi) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
          else {  
            for(int i=0; i<selec.length; i++){
                for(int j=0;j<sintom.length;j++){

                   //  si[i].executeUpdate(var[(i*sintom.length)+j]);
                   ps.setString(1, malattia);
                   ps.setInt(2, eta);
                   ps.setString(3, descrizione);
                   ps.setString(4, sexarra[0] );
                   ps.setString(5, selec[i]);
                   ps.setString(6, sintom[j]);

                   ps.executeUpdate();
                }
               }
            }



                   //st.executeUpdate(q);
                    ps.close();
                    conn.close();
                    ris = "si";
              } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println("Errore: " + e.getMessage());
                    return ris;
              }
        }
        return ris;
  }
```

The server sends back **ris** which is either **si** or **no** depending on the success of the query, here i get **si** if **sintom** which is the length of the inner loop to be 1 otherwise i get **no** I don't know exactly what causes it to respond with a **no** furthermore this is a SOAP based web-service, i can debug the client part of the system not the server part

Comment: do you get an exception or does your program terminate cleanly?

Comment: Actually since its on the server side of the Web-Service I can't exactly see what is the cause. Suppose, the inner loop has length 2 it would do the query for Sintom[0], the first element but stop from executing the query after that.

Comment: If its your code thats on the server, then you should be able to see it. Its hard to help if you can't see errors/output. I can't see anything glaring in your code.

Comment: Ofcourse it is my code :) i just updated the question, hope it clears up my question. Thanks for ur effort!

Comment: I reformatted the code and it is clear stuff is missing -- you have an else without an if, etc.  Please check the code posted.

Comment: @Hogan, thanks but I thought of only focusing on the code which is giving me the problem i.e where the query is being executed in the nested loop, thought other code was trivial for the moment. I still have the problem, is the way i execute the query and using the loop especially the internal loop valid? how the variable are passed.

Comment: The loops are fine -- the problem is somewhere else that is why I was looking at the other code, but it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After beating my head for hours and hours, the problem laid in the Database!! what happend was that since the column **sintomi** was a FK referencing a table of Sintomi which was multivalued, it was therefore a primarykey of the table malattia SO the values which i was passing needed to have been already present in the table sintomi so column **sintomi** could reference it!! Anyways it would have been impossible to understand that from the information i provided, Thanks everybody! as always great, you guys are there when things get outta control.